# Wiped data, and duplicated folders into files

Tags: data-recovery

Something weird happened today, and I dont know how. Within a folder, all folders have a file by the same name, with a colon appended to it. And all the files from the most inner-most directory in my home, have been dumped to ~, with a size of 0 bytes.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

I have not executed any scripts or anything. I was just checking out some easter eggs, namely the `gegls from outer space` and `free the fish` and was away from the computer and was logged because of the screensaver. I couldnt log-back in with my password, so I just reset the PC, and while booting, the PC went into a drive check. BUT, IIRC, i saw the duplicate "folder files" before I had logged out, so thats not the reason! All the files have a timestamp of 14 Jan. Also, the contents of my eclipse folder have been dumped into ~. Right down to the jars and ini files.

HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete all files ending with **:** with this command:

```
find -name *: | xargs rm
```

You should **execute** `find -name *:` **first** to check what will be removed.

Comment: @theTuxRacer I wouldn't do that just yet as it will deter users who actually have a solution. Remember that you can always set a bounty.